# ExpandableListView binding with SimpleCursorTreeAdapter

Tags: android, expandablelistview, simplecursortreeadapter

I have tried to bind `ExpandableListView` using `SimpleCursorTreeAdapter` but i'm facing problem to bind correctly.

#### My Java Code:

```
void fillData() {
    orderDeliveryCursor = dbHelper.getOrderDelivery(order_id);

    Log.d(TAG, "Count "+orderDeliveryCursor.getCount());

    if(orderDeliveryCursor != null && orderDeliveryCursor.getCount() > 0) {
        // Cache the ID column index
        groupId = orderDeliveryCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DatabaseHelper.ORDER_DELIVERY_SERVER_ID);

        // Set up our adapter
        adapter = new MyExpandableListAdapter(orderDeliveryCursor, context, 

            R.layout.frag_dispatch_header_layout,           // Header layout
            R.layout.frag_dispatch_order_product_child_layout,      // Dispatch Details Child Layout

            new String[] { DatabaseHelper.ORDER_DELIVERY_SERVER_ID, DatabaseHelper.ORDER_DELIVERY_INVOICE_ID, DatabaseHelper.ORDER_DELIVERY_TRANSPORT },    // group title for group layouts
            new int[] { R.id.dispatchHeaderDeliveryId, R.id.dispatchHeaderInvoice, R.id.dispatchHeaderTransport },

            new String[] { },   // exercise title for child layouts
            new int[] { });

        expandableListView.setAdapter(adapter);

        expandableListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        errorTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {

        errorTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        expandableListView.setVisibility(View.GONE);    
    }
    }

    // extending SimpleCursorTreeAdapter
    public class MyExpandableListAdapter extends SimpleCursorTreeAdapter {

    public MyExpandableListAdapter(Cursor cursor, Context context,
        int groupLayout, int childLayout, String[] groupFrom,
        int[] groupTo, String[] childrenFrom, int[] childrenTo) {
        super(context, cursor, groupLayout, groupFrom, groupTo,
            childLayout, childrenFrom, childrenTo);
    }

    // returns cursor with subitems for given group cursor
    @Override
    protected Cursor getChildrenCursor(Cursor groupCursor) {
        Cursor exercisesCursor = dbHelper.getOrderDeliveryProduct(groupCursor.getInt(groupId));
        Log.d(TAG, "child Count : "+exercisesCursor.getCount() + " : " +groupCursor.getInt(groupId)+ " : "+groupCursor.getInt(groupCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.ORDER_DELIVERY_SERVER_ID)));
        return exercisesCursor;
    }

    // I needed to process click on click of the button on child item
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public View getChildView(final int groupPosition,
        final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView,
        ViewGroup parent) {

        View rowView = super.getChildView(groupPosition, childPosition,
            isLastChild, convertView, parent);

        ((TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.dispatchInvoiceDateValue))
        .setText(orderDeliveryCursor.isNull(orderDeliveryCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.ORDER_DELIVERY_INVOICE_DATE)) 
            ? ""
                : orderDeliveryCursor.getString(orderDeliveryCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.ORDER_DELIVERY_INVOICE_DATE)));

        ((TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.dispatchInvoiceAmountValue))
        .setText(orderDeliveryCursor.isNull(orderDeliveryCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.ORDER_DELIVERY_INVOICE_AMOUNT)) 
            ? ""
                : orderDeliveryCursor.getString(orderDeliveryCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.ORDER_DELIVERY_INVOICE_AMOUNT)));

        ((TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.dispatchLRnoValue))
        .setText(orderDeliveryCursor.isNull(orderDeliveryCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.ORDER_DELIVERY_LR_NO)) 
            ? ""
                : orderDeliveryCursor.getString(orderDeliveryCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.ORDER_DELIVERY_LR_NO)));

        ((TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.dispatchLRDateValue))
        .setText(orderDeliveryCursor.isNull(orderDeliveryCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.ORDER_DELIVERY_LR_DATE)) 
            ? ""
                : orderDeliveryCursor.getString(orderDeliveryCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.ORDER_DELIVERY_LR_DATE)));

        /***
         * 
         * Process for INNER PRODUCTS
         * 
         */
        orderDeliveryProductCursor = dbHelper.getOrderDeliveryProduct(orderDeliveryCursor.getInt(orderDeliveryCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.ORDER_DELIVERY_SERVER_ID)));

        /**
         * Fill PRODUCT BY ORDERID
         */
        TableLayout productTableLayout = (TableLayout) rowView.findViewById(R.id.dispatchProductTableLayout);

        if(!dbHelper.db.isOpen())
        dbHelper.open();

        LinearLayout row;

        if(orderDeliveryProductCursor.getCount() > 0)
        { 
        int totalQty = 0;
        while (orderDeliveryProductCursor.moveToNext()) {
            String prodId = orderDeliveryProductCursor.getString(orderDeliveryProductCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.ORDER_PRODUCT_PRODUCT_ID));    

            /*** Creating Dynamic View for Product List ***/
            View childView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.frag_dispatch_product_list, null);

            TextView prodName;
            TextView prodQty;

            row = new LinearLayout(context);

            row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            prodName = (TextView) childView.findViewById(R.id.dispatchProductNameValue);
            prodName.setText(""+dbHelper.getProductName(prodId));

            int qty = orderDeliveryProductCursor.getInt(orderDeliveryProductCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.O_D_P_QUANTITY));

            totalQty += qty;

            prodQty = (TextView) childView.findViewById(R.id.dispatchProductQuantityValue);
            prodQty.setText(""+qty);

            row.addView(childView);
            productTableLayout.addView(row);

        }//while orderProductCursor.moveToNext()

        BigDecimal amt = new BigDecimal(totalQty).setScale(2, RoundingMode.DOWN);
        /*** for Total Amount ***/
        ((TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.dispatchQuantityTotal)).setText("Total : "+amt);
        }


        //if orderProductCursor.getCount() > 0
        return rowView;
    }

    }
```

### Output:

I got output like this, First time i got correctly

### FirstTime:

[image]

### SecondTime when I open child, I got like:

[image]

How can i solve this??

Comment: id recommend extending basecursortreeadapter instead of simple one, makes it easiert to customize since you can handle everythign for yourself. to me it looks like your newView method(provided by simple cursoradapter) is called too often. or your data changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After two days i found my mistake which i have done in `getChildCursor();`

I have changed like:

```
// returns cursor with subitems for given group cursor
@Override
protected Cursor getChildrenCursor(Cursor groupCursor) {
    Cursor exercisesCursor = dbHelper.getOrderDeliveryId(groupCursor.getInt(groupId));
    Log.d(TAG, "child Count : "+exercisesCursor.getCount() + " : " +groupCursor.getInt(groupId)+ " : "+groupCursor.getInt(groupCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.ORDER_DELIVERY_ORDER_ID)));
    return exercisesCursor;
}
```

Which returns 1 everytime which i actually want: